# In gmake, how to reuse the results of a function without calling it again?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Consider the below `GNUmakefile`:

```
V=  $(shell set -x; date)

all:
    @echo 1 $V
    @echo 2 $V
    @echo 3 $V
```

If you run it, the `shell`-macro can be seen invoked three times -- invoking three separate shells, each one calling date(1).

While I understand, why this may be useful in *some* cases, it is quite wasteful in others.

How can I refer to the results of an earlier invocation of a macro -- without causing it to be invoked again each time?

Note, this seems to be specific to GNU-make. The seemingly equivalent construct of BSD's make, for example, only calls the shell once, no matter, how many times you reuse the variable later:

```
V!= set -x; date

all:
    @echo 1 $V
    @echo 2 $V
    @echo 3 $V
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer is that `=` in GNU make is not equivalent to `!=` in BSD make.  The operator `=` in GNU make is equivalent to the `=` operator in BSD make.

If you want to evaluate things only one time, use [the `:=` operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html) in GNU make.  Or, if you have GNU make 4.0 or above, it supports the [BSD-style `!=` operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Setting.html) as well.

Comment: Yay! The `:=` is it. Thanks!